# Manipulating all split data sets

Tags: r

I'm drawing a blank-- I have 51 sets of split data from a data frame that I had, and I want to take the mean of the height of each set.

```
print(dataset)
$`1`
ID   Species  Plant   Height 
1      A        1      42.7
2      A        1      32.5

$`2`
ID   Species  Plant   Height 
3      A        2      43.5
4      A        2      54.3
5      A        2      45.7
```

...

...

...

```
$`51`
ID   Species  Plant   Height
134     A       51     52.5
135     A       51     61.2
```

I know how to run each individually, but with 51 split sections, it would take me ages.

I thought that

```
mean(dataset[,4])
```

might work, but it says that I have the wrong number of dimensions. I get now why that is incorrect, but I am no closer to figuring out how to average all of the heights.

Answer (score 5):

The `dataset` is a `list`.  We could use `lapply/sapply/vapply` etc to loop through the `list` elements and get the mean of the 'Height' column.  Using `vapply`, we can specify the `class` and `length` of the output (`numeric(1))`.  This will be useful for debugging.

```
vapply(dataset, function(x) mean(x[,4], na.rm=TRUE), numeric(1))
#     1        2       51 
#37.60000 47.83333 56.85000
```

---

Or another option (if we have the same columnames/number of columns for the `data.frame`s in the `list`), would be to use `rbindlist` from `data.table` with the `option`idcol=TRUE`to generate a single`data.table`.  The '.id' column shows the name of the`list`elements.  We group by '.id' and get the`mean`of the`Height`.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(dataset, idcol=TRUE)[, list(Mean=mean(Height, na.rm=TRUE)), by = .id]
#   .id     Mean
#1:   1 37.60000
#2:   2 47.83333
#3:  51 56.85000
```

Or a similar option as above is `unnest` from `library(tidyr)` to return a single dataset with the '.id' column, grouped by '.id', we `summarise` to get the `mean` of 'Height'.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
unnest(dataset, .id) %>%
          group_by(.id) %>% 
          summarise(Mean= mean(Height, na.rm=TRUE))
# .id     Mean
#1   1 37.60000
#2   2 47.83333
#3  51 56.85000
```

The syntax for `plyr` is

```
df1 <- unnest(dataset, .id)
ddply(df1, .(.id), summarise, Mean=mean(Height, na.rm=TRUE))
# .id     Mean
#1   1 37.60000
#2   2 47.83333
#3  51 56.85000
```

#### data

```
dataset <- structure(list(`1` = structure(list(ID = 1:2, Species = c("A", 
"A"), Plant = c(1L, 1L), Height = c(42.7, 32.5)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Species", "Plant", "Height"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)), `2` = structure(list(ID = 3:5, Species = c("A", "A", "A"
), Plant = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Height = c(43.5, 54.3, 45.7)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Species", "Plant", "Height"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), `51` = structure(list(ID = 134:135, Species = c("A", "A"
), Plant = c(51L, 51L), Height = c(52.5, 61.2)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Species", "Plant", "Height"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))), .Names = c("1", "2", "51"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Would I be able to use plyr instead of dplyr? I know that they are similar, but I am a little bit more familiar (although I am still just now learning) plyr.

Comment: @Adam Yes, you can use that.  In that case after the `unnest`. i.e. `df1 <- unnest(dataset, .id); library(plyr); ddply(df1, .(.id), summarize, mean(Height, na.rm=TRUE))` (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

This also works, though it uses dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
1:length(dataset) %>%
  lapply(function(i)
    test[[i]] %>%
      mutate(section = i ) ) %>%
   bind_rows %>%
   group_by(section) %>%
   summarize(mean_height = mean(height) )
```